# What are the various approaches to detect whether a sentence is complete or not?

Tags: computational-linguistics, machine-translation, language-models, text-classification

I was working on creating a question answering system. Now I wanted to deal with incomplete or partial sentences. So the first step to this would be detecting whether the question entered by the user is complete or incomplete. How do I classify "Who is Obama's Wife" as complete and "Obama's Wife" as incomplete?

Answer (score 2):

For formal English anyway you can parse with spaCy and then iterate through the tagged tokens looking for a finite verb (`VerbForm=Fin`, as opposed to `Ger` or `Inf`).

See https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#rule-based-morphology

Comment: Hey! I am working with a search engine here. So basically most of the queries would be partially complete. I want to check if the sentence is partially complete or absolutely keyword based.